# How do you UPDATE an identity column in SQL azure? Is it possible?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have this code:

```
ALTER TABLE FishSticks
ADD MyNewIdentityColumnId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL

SET IDENTITY_INSERT FishSticks ON

UPDATE FishSticks 
SET MyNewIdentityColumnId = MyOldColumnId
```

However it says:

> Cannot update identity column 'MyNewIdentityColumnId'.

I assume this is due to SQL Azure, but I didn't have much success googling. It seems that changing a column to be an identity while preserving data is a huge difficulty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SET IDENTITY_INSERT only works for INSERTS and that error is not specific to SQL Azure. You'll get the same error on SQL Server/Express

to go around the issue, SET IDENTITY_INSERT  to ON, reinsert all the column values from the existing row whose identity value you want to replace with a new value, SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF, then delete the previous row.

Comment: Another approach, along the same lines, is to copy the table to a new table entirely (let's say FishSticks2), set your MyNewIdentityColumnId to MyOldColumnId during the insert, drop the original table, and rename FishSticks2 to FishSticks.

Comment: It will only work with Azure if you use the full INSERT command, i.e. include all column names.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [Possible solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/ssdsgetstarted/thread/ceeae474-fb19-4282-a56b-c0718f06e9ab) from Herve Roggero who basically gives a way of turning off the ID and then adding the rows, then turning ID back on.

Comment: I think his example works because he is inserting data, whereas I am updating data.